# Какими командами можно переместиться текущим указателем на указанный коммит, при этом не изменяя файлов в рабочей директории?

Tags: git, github, git-reset

Какими командами можно переместиться текущим указателем на указанный коммит, при этом не изменяя файлов в рабочей директории? Желательно с пояснениями
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

git reset позволяет сбросить состояние проекта до какого-либо коммита в истории. В git данное действие может быть двух видов: «мягкого»(soft reset) и «жесткого» (hard reset).

«Мягкий» (с ключом "--soft") сброс оставит нетронутыми ваши индекс (а практика показывает, что тронет индекс) и все дерево  файлов и директорий проекта, вернется к работе с указанным коммитом. То есть, файлы в рабочем каталоге останутся нетронутыми, то есть отката состояния файлов в рабочей директории до состояния в указанном коммите не произойдет (в отличие от опции --hard). То есть, сдвинется только указатель в истории, без изменения файлов в рабочей директории.

Comment: Данное действие бывает трёх видов. Есть еще --mixed, который делает то, что вы приписываете soft'у